# Using a variable created in foreach

Tags: c#

I am trying to extract duplicates compared from an XML file and a DB table column

Here is my current code

```
using (AH_ODS_DBEntities db = new AH_ODS_DBEntities())
{
    //XML CustomerRefNbr            
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\");
    foreach (var @CRN in allFiles)
    {
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@CRN);
        IEnumerable<XElement> invoices = xEle.Elements();
        foreach (XElement pEle in invoices)
        {
            string c = pEle.Element("CustomerRef").Value;
        }

        //DB CustomerRefNbr
        IEnumerable<string> rs = db.Sales.AsQueryable().Select(crn => crn.CustomerRefNbr);
        foreach (string invoice in rs)
        {
            string i = invoice;
        }
    }

}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is to get string c and i, compare if they have a match and put them in a list.

```
var duplicateCRN= db.Sales.SqlQuery("SELECT  * FROM Sales WHERE " + i + "==" + c)
                            .ToList<Sale>();
```

Not sure if I'm doing this right though.

Comment: The inner loops doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you want to check if any element in the xml contains the same value as any entry from the database right?

What you're doing now in the foreach does not do anything, because you just overwrite the values, but do nothing with it.

Check this code:

```
using (AH_ODS_DBEntities db = new AH_ODS_DBEntities())
{
    //XML CustomerRefNbr            
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\");
    foreach (var @CRN in allFiles)
    {
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@CRN);
        IEnumerable<XElement> invoices = xEle.Elements();
        foreach (XElement pEle in invoices)
        {
            string c = pEle.Element("CustomerRef").Value;
            //DB CustomerRefNbr
            IEnumerable<string> rs = db.Sales.AsQueryable().Select(crn => crn.CustomerRefNbr);
            foreach (string invoice in rs)
            {
                if (invoice == c);
                    //This is a match
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can do this also directly with Linq to SQL, which is the preferred way (better perfomance)

```
    //XML CustomerRefNbr            
    string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\");
    foreach (var @CRN in allFiles)
    {
        XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@CRN);
        IEnumerable<XElement> invoices = xEle.Elements();
        foreach (XElement pEle in invoices)
        {
            string c = pEle.Element("CustomerRef").Value;
            //DB CustomerRefNbr
            using (AH_ODS_DBEntities db = new AH_ODS_DBEntities())
            {
                List<string> rs = db.Sales.Where(s => s.CustomerRefNbr == c).ToList();
                if (rs.Any())
                {
                    //all items in rs are matches
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You should initialize the string i and c before the foreach. This way you can fill it in the foreach and use it in later in your code. So like this:

```
using (AH_ODS_DBEntities db = new AH_ODS_DBEntities())
        {
            //XML CustomerRefNbr            
            string[] allFiles = Directory.GetFiles(@"C:\xml\");
            string i = "";
            string c = "";
            foreach (var @CRN in allFiles)
            {
                XElement xEle = XElement.Load(@CRN);
                IEnumerable<XElement> invoices = xEle.Elements();
                foreach (XElement pEle in invoices)
                {
                    c = pEle.Element("CustomerRef").Value;
                }

                //DB CustomerRefNbr
                IEnumerable<string> rs = db.Sales.AsQueryable().Select(crn => crn.CustomerRefNbr);
                foreach (string invoice in rs)
                {
                    i = invoice;
                }
            }

        }
```

Comment: Still this just sets `c` and `i` to the last value in the collection.

Comment: ofcourse, so you can better do "c +=" and "i +=" instead of "=" or use list instead of strings, but that wasn't the question.

Comment: No, this was not what he meant ;). Your foreach loop does always override the value, till it reaches the end of the collection. Be aware that `=` does override, and `+=` and `-=` do add or substract (and therefore cannot be applied to `strings`)

Comment: I know, but I answered before question was adjusted, so misinterpretated what he asked. I also plussed your answer because it is indeed better, and he should use that.